# Failed to list methods for service "xxx": Symbol not found: xxx

Tags: go, grpc, grpcurl

**Error**

```
./grpcurl_linux -plaintext host:port list
a.b
c.d
./grpcurl_linux -plaintext host:port describe a.b
Failed to list methods for service "a.b": Symbol not found: a.b
```

**Env**

```
protoc --version
libprotoc 3.6.0
```

why??? bug???

Comment: Is the server using grpc-go? And if so, has the reflection service been registered? See: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.48.0/reflection#section-readme

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We have insufficient information. Please provide a full repro for the issue including a proto file and the server code. It is curious that `list` works but `describe` does not. If the server doesn't support reflection, I think the error message would be "server does not support the reflection API"

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. The server does support reflection api. Did you find a solution to this?